# Error extraño cuando uso el Componente de Navegación de Android, sólo funciona cuando cargo el fragmento la primera vez

Tags: android, android-componente-de-navegacion

Estoy usando el [Componente de Navegación de Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started?hl=es-419) para cargar un fragmento cuando el usuario haga clic en una opción de menú.

Yo puedo estar en cualquier fragmento, por ejemplo, este fragmento se llama `Lecturas`  y en la barra superior del mismo hay una opción para cargar otro fragmento llamado `Calendario`.

Lo que ocurre es que **la primera vez todo funciona bien**. Es decir, si estoy en `Lecturas` y hago clic en la opción de calendario, me carga el fragmento `Calendario` (es un DatePicker), yo puedo escoger otra fecha y cargar de nuevo el fragmento anterior (`Lecturas`) u otro, con datos de esa fecha escogida.

Pues bien, **la segunda vez el código no funciona de la forma esperada**. Todo se carga bien, pero si hago clic en el icono de calendario (barra superior) ya no carga al fragmento de Calendario. Es como si no reconociera que estoy queriendo navegar a ese destino.

Poniendo puntos de interrupción en el código, el mismo pasa por el método `onOptionsItemSelected()` y no hay nada nulo, simplemente no reconoce el destino **a partir de la segunda vez**.

Esta es la parte relevante del código:

#### En `navigation.xml`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_calendario"
    android:name="org.deiverbum.app.ui.fragments.CalendarioFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_fragment_calendario"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_calendario" />
```

#### Menú

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_calendario"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar_toolbar"
    android:title="@string/all_calendar"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

#### Fragmento (lecturas u otro)

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    // ...

    return root;
}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    mainMenu=menu;
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item_voz) {
        if (mActionMode == null){
            mActionMode=requireActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
        }
        readText();
        isReading = true;
        requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }

    setPlayerButton();
    NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

¿Por qué la primera vez funciona y a partir de la segunda vez ya deja de funcionar?

He puesto sólo la parte relevante del código (pues es un contexto más complejo, con más código), sin embargo, si hace falta algo más me dicen.

El código para navegar sería este:

```
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Aquí, debería reconocer en `item` el destino `nav_calendario` indicado más arriba en mi `navigation.xml`.

Comment: en el navigation.xml, tienes múltiples action de cada destination? Ej: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs